# Reloading a JTree during runtime

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtree

I create a JTree and model for it out in a class separate to the GUI class. The data for the JTree is extracted from a file.

Now in the GUI class the user can add files from the file system to an AWT list. After the user clicks on a file in the list I want the JTree to update. The variable name for the JTree is schemaTree.

I have the following code for the when an item in the list is selected:

```
private void schemaListItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
        int selection = schemaList.getSelectedIndex();
        File selectedFile = schemas.get(selection);
        long fileSize = selectedFile.length();
        fileInfoLabel.setText("Size: " + fileSize + " bytes");

        schemaParser = new XSDParser(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());

        TreeModel model = schemaParser.generateTreeModel();
        schemaTree.setModel(model);
}
```

I've updated the code to correspond to the accepted answer. The JTree now updates correctly based on which file I select in the list.

Comment: I've posted a follow on question here: http://bit.ly/iaDqS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure that I'm understanding your question, but I'll try...

The right thing to do should be, IMHO:

- get the file
- create a new TreeModel from your file
- give the model to the JTree

In pseudocode, it would look like that:

```
File newContent = getSelectedByUser(...);
TreeModel newModel = new MyFileBasedTreeModel(newContent);
//this next part must be done in the EventDispatcherThread
myTree.setModel(newModel);
```

then the JTree would be updated, without any call to repaint, etc.

Hope it helps

Comment: Very good, I've now modified the method generateTree() to return the model instead of the tree and renamed the method generateTreeModel(). The tree now updates correctly based on which file I click in the list. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the [`Component.add`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)) API docs.

> Note: If a component has been added to
>   a container that has been displayed,
>   validate must be called on that
>   container to display the new
>   component. If multiple components are
>   being added, you can improve
>   efficiency by calling validate only
>   once, after all the components have
>   been added.

You have called `repaint` and `validate` on a component that is not displayed, which will not be effective. You need to call those methods on the `mainPanel` after the `add`. Also `revalidate` tends to be better than `validate` as it effectively coalesces.

Comment: I've tried revalidate on the mainPanel however the JTree still doesn't  update. I'll modify the code in the original question to what I have now

Comment: It looks like you've now not added the new tree to the panel.

Comment: Works now .. I now don't remove the JTree at all, I just wasn't updating the model in the correct place.

Thanks for your reply